# Getting Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." while posting image to with parameters to server

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I am using Afnetworking 3.0 , for image uploading with some other parameters i use this code

```
NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_profileImageView.image, 1.0);//(uploadedImgView.image);
        NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [params setValue:_tf_email.text forKey:@"email"];
        [params setValue:_tf_password.text forKey:@"password"];
        [params setValue:_tf_userType.text forKey:@"userType"];
        [params setValue:_tf_country.text forKey:@"country"];
        [params setValue:_tf_name.text forKey:@"name"];
        [params setValue:@"3.423434" forKey:@"longitude"];
        [params setValue:@"72.32445" forKey:@"latitude"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BaseUrl,Register] parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageToUpload name:@"profilePicture" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",_tf_name.text] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        } error:nil];

       // AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
        responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html",@"charset=UTF-8", nil];


        manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;


        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
        uploadTask = [manager
                      uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                      progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                          // This is not called back on the main queue.
                          // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                              //Update the progress view
                              //[progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
                              NSLog(@"%f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
                          });
                      }
                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
                          }
                      }];

        [uploadTask resume];
```

> Note : profilePicture is my key to service  its giving me error 
>   Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 1.}

Comment: Check server image model parameter should be "profilePicture"

Comment: its same in the model...